# Delete empty lines from a text file via Bash including empty spaces characters

Tags: linux, bash

I tried to use 'sed' command to remove the empty lines.

```
sed -i '/^$/d' file.txt
```

My sample txt file looks likes this. The second line has space characters. sed command only removes the empty lines but not the lines with white space.

```
Sample text

Sample text
```

So is there away to accomplish this via bash.

My intended out put is

```
Sample text
Sample text
```

Comment: What's your intended output, **exactly**? Do you want `testline`? Do you want any line with any whitespace in it at all to be deleted?

Comment: try `sed '/^\s*$/d'`

Comment: ...should the file just contain `testlinetestline`, no whitespace *including* newlines? (That's actually *really* easy, being a job `tr` can do).

Comment: My intended output is (test line \n test line) I want the second empty line with spaces to be removed in the output file.

Comment: @MichaelCoker, `\s` isn't defined by BRE or ERE; `[[:space:]]` is the portable way to write it.

Comment: @NirojanSelvanathan, ...re: making intended output clear, edit the question with that. You might also want to include a line that *should* be kept in the sample content, just so someone trying to be funny can't tell you to write `> yourfile` as an answer that works with the test data given.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use character class `[:blank:]` to indicate space or tab:

With `sed`:

```
sed -i '/^[[:blank:]]*$/ d' file.txt
```

With `perl`:

```
perl -ne 'print if !/^[[:blank:]]*$/' file.txt
```

With `awk`:

```
awk '!/^[[:blank:]]*$/' file.txt
```

With `grep`:

```
grep -v '^[[:blank:]]*$' file.txt
```

---

If the tool does not support editing in-place, leverage a temporary file e.g. for `grep`:

```
grep -v '^[[:blank:]]*$' file.txt >file.txt.tmp && mv file.txt{.tmp,}
```

Comment: I use MINGW64's msys (git_bash from GitForWindows) and have to deals with native Windows exe's output quite oftens (e.g. WMIC, ping etc.), to work with these ones, include a '\r' in your character class: `/^[[:blank:]\r]*$/`

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i '/^ *$/d' file.txt
```

or to also match other white space characters such as tabs, etc:

```
sed -i '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' file.txt
```

the * character matches 0 or more instances of preceding character

Comment: `\s` for any type of whitespace, not just spaces.

Comment: Or `[[:space:]]` for a preference.

Comment: `\s` isn't guaranteed to work in POSIX `sed`. This is a place where unless there's a specific implementation specified in the question that's known to support PCRE extensions, I'd argue that specifying anything other than the POSIX BRE syntax is *wrong*.

Comment: I just tested `'/^\s*$/d'` on Mac OS X 10.11.6, GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15) and it didn't match some lines with just spaces, but the following did work:   `'/^[[:space:]]*$/d'`

Comment: @user122992, ...to be clear, btw, it's the version of `sed`, as opposed to the version of bash, that matters.